# avoid null reference exception when trying to retrieve children of unexisting parents with linq to xml

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

Is there an easy way to avoid null reference exception when accessing childs elements of unexisting parents ? For example I have this query:

```
            Persons = (from actor in xDoc.Root.Element(imdbns + "Cast").Elements(imdbns + "Actor")
                       select new Person { Name = (string)actor.Element(imdbns + "Person").Element(imdbns + "Name"), Role = "Actor" }).Union(
                       from director in xDoc.Root.Element(imdbns + "Directors").Elements(imdbns + "Person")
                       select new Person { Name = (string)director.Element(imdbns + "Name"), Role = "Director" }).Union(
                       from writer in xDoc.Root.Descendants(imdbns + "Writer")
                       select new Person { Name = (string)writer.Element(imdbns + "Person").Element(imdbns + "Name"), Role = "Writer" }).ToList()
```

It unifies three elements (actor, writer, director) into a an object Person. The problem is that I don't know in advance if the element "Cast" exists, or the element "Directors". These elements are the parent elements of the final elements that I need to access, and in case they do not exists I will get an null reference exception. So my question is: do I have to break the query into a unreadable set of sequences "if != null then" or is there a more handy way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the check first. Something along the lines of

```
if(xDoc.Root.Element(imdbns + "Cast") != null && xDoc.Root.Element(imdbns + "Directors" != null)
{
   Persons = (from actor in ...
}
```